# Parsing rows from MySQL into files using PHP is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to parse an entire MySQL table into files named after the rows. However, it seems to miss out a lot of files, and it just isn't working properly, but I don't understand what's wrong. Here's what I'm using:

```
$link = mysql_connect(...); //*Let's assume this is correct*
mysql_select_db(*This too*);
$query = "SELECT * FROM rules";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num = mysql_num_rows($result) or die(mysql_error());
for($x = 0;$x < $num;$x++) {
    $rules = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $file = '';
    if($rules['except'])
        $file .= $common = str_replace(explode(',', $rules['except']), "", $common);
    if($rules['custom'])
        $file .= $rules['custom'];
    if($rules['css'])
        $file .= trim($rules['css'], ";")."{display:none !important;height:0px !important;width:0px !important;}";
    if($file == '') {
        $handle = fopen($rules['site'].'.css', 'w');
        fwrite($handle, $file);
    }
}
```

Can anyone see anything wrong?

Comment: You're missing some code (within the for block). Edit your post and indent 4 spaces before to code to properly format it

Comment: yeah .... there is no formatting and seems the code block isnt complete as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem you're searching is in this line `if($file == '') {`. It will be true only if `$file` is empty. But I think you need an oposite condition like following:

```
if($file != '') {
```

Also I suggest you to always close the file you've opened:

```
if($file != '') {
   $handle = fopen($rules['site'].'.css', 'w');
   fwrite($handle, $file);
   fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i am not mistaken by looking at it, seems like this line:

```
$file .= $common = str_replace(explode(',', $rules['except']), "", $common);
```

would always be empty.